# Error: process_executor.py:702: ... A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib

As per error in the subject, what is the fix?

Environment:

- Python 3.9 or 3.10
- Windows 10 x64

Error occurs when using [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for parallel processing:

```
result_chunks = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=njobs)(joblib.delayed(f_chunk)(i) for i in n_chunks)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002095/joblib-worker-stopped-caused-by-timeout-or-memory-leak/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is too short a timeout. It is caused when there is a lot of data to pass to the child processes and it times out internally. This warning is benign, joblib recovers internally and the results (in my experience) are accurate and complete.

To fix, increase timeout, I used this:

```
# Increase timeout (tune this number to suit your use case).
timeout=99999
result_chunks = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=njobs, timeout=timeout)(joblib.delayed(f_chunk)(i) for i in n_chunks)
```

Alternatively, figure out a way to reduce the amount of data that has to be serialized and sent to the child processes.

#### Update 2022-04-03

This can also occur, regardless of timeout, if `n_jobs` is so  high that total CPU usage is running close to 100%, e.g. 95%. The fix is to reduce njobs so total CPU usage drops, e.g. to 85%.

#### Update 2022-04-03

Also observed this happened when I was using [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/) within each job, regardless of timeout and total CPU usage. It did not seem to happen when I switched back to Pandas. This could be as Polars is more efficient and uses more CPU, or (as the error mentions) due to a memory leak (which is unlikely).

#### Update 2023-02-20

Joblib v1.2.0 was released on 2022-11-16. It is possible that this new version fixes the issue, according to answer from @yairchu.

Comment: Where is the cited quote from ("Note: This warning is benign, joblib recovers internally and the results are accurate and complete.")? I did a google search and this answer is the only source that comes up.

Comment: @Will Not intended as a quote; the ">" was intended as emphasis. Edited answer to remove ">".

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading `joblib` from version 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 did the trick for me! (the `timeout` solution didn't change anything for me)